# Merge 2 rows into one filling empty fields

Tags: php, arrays, merge

So, I have been searching but I could not find something similair.
What I need is to merge 2 rows what I got from DB (stored in an Array) and fill out empty fields.

We have 2 keys FIXED and WEIGHT and they have different values in columns. If we use FIXED type we do not use values from WEIGHT and those columns are empty, now I have to merge those 2 2rows into one.

There is N rows (but always in pair).

Here is example

```
id type   postal fix_price weight_price our_price your_price product_id group_id
1  fixed  8888   50        -            50        -          1          2
2  weight 8888   -         100          -         100        1          2
3  fixed  7777   20        -            20        -          1          2
4  weight 7777   -         30           -         30         1          2
```

And I need result like below:

```
id postal fix_price weight_price our_price your_price product_id group_id
1  8888   50        100          50        100        1          2
2  7777   20         30          20        30         1          2
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: anything you've tried so far? should be quite easy looping through the result...

Comment: Try something like select postal, max(fix_price), max(weight_price), max(our_price), max(your_price) from table group by postal

Comment: Rakesh Kumar - Its pure php thing (I need to combine data from 1 array based on key -> Type = (fixed/weight) and those 2 key are always in pair

@Jeff I have tried with $arra1 + $array2, (before I have make an foreach loop and save in array 1 all rows with type-fixed and array 2 with type-weight, then also tried with array_filter($array1)+array_filter($array2); and combine_arrays but that is not what I need 

thx for supporting

Comment: Ahm, from where does `2  7777   30` <-- the first 30 come in your result???

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions That is bug during typing (I have edited post). Thx for noticed me :)

Comment: I dont get this part ` If we use FIXED type we do not use values from`?!

Comment: That mean that we are importing prices and during import we have all prices into single row, then during save we are spliting prices into 2 rows (fixed, weight) and using only cells what we need for each type. After this process there is option to download prices and in this step we need to merge those 2 rows like one (actually to get document like we have uploaded)... I hope so that this explanation is good enough... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$collect=array();
$useType='fixed';
foreach($array as $set){
    $check=$set['type'];
    unset($set['type']);
    if(!isset($collect[$set['postal']])) {
        $collect[$set['postal']] = $set;
    } else {
        foreach($set as $k=>$v){
            if($k=='id' && $check!=$useType)   {
                continue;
            }
            if(!empty($v)){
                $collect[$set['postal']][$k] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
}
$collect=array_values($collect);
var_export($collect);
```

This produces your expacted result, but i dont thing that is what you really want.

Comment: This is not what I want actually. Here you can see on this link my data structure http://www.sharecsv.com/s/2b84a6eaa2ed094c05de60ea547cffab/prices.csv 
When you open that file from row 2 to row 30 is type "weightand" and from 31 to 59 type is "fixed". 
So I want to fill out column "Main" and "weight_pr" with fields from type fixed in columns "Main" and "weight_pr" and in that case I have only 28 rows with all data (now its 58 rows)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand how your question is related with the (very different) data structure you shared in your comment under the @JustOnUnderMillions answer, so here is an answer based on the structure suggested by your initial question.

Taking advantage of your other comment where you say "I have tried with $arra1 + $array2" I guess you're able to first format the source data like this:

```
$fixed = [
  8888 => [50, NULL, 50, NULL, 1, 2],
  7777 => [20, NULL, 20, NULL, 1, 2],
];
$weight = [
  8888 => [NULL, 100, NULL, 100, 1, 2],
  7777 => [NULL, 30, NULL, 30, 1, 2],
];
```

Then it's pretty easy to use this simple code:

```
foreach ($fixed AS $postal => $fixed_data) {
  $weight_data = $weight[$postal];
  foreach ($fixed_data AS $key => $fixed_value) {
    $all[$postal][$key] = $fixed_value ? $fixed_value : $weight_data[$key];
  }
}
```

which gives the expected result:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($all, TRUE) . '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [8888] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 50
            [3] => 100
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 2
        )

    [7777] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 30
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 2
        )

)
*/
```